# What is the elegant way to `watch docker ps --format`?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, unix, watch

## Problem

I'm trying to `watch` my running containers, with command like this:

```sh
watch docker ps --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Command}}"
```

but instead of nice output in the format of

```
IMAGE     NAMES     COMMAND
...       ...       ...
```

I get

```
"docker ps" accepts no arguments.
See 'docker ps --help'.

Usage:  docker ps [OPTIONS]

List containers
```

Is there any elegant way to do watch running containers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

Shortly after posting this question I found solution.

Adding single-quotes `'...'` solves the problem.

```sh
watch 'docker ps --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Command}}"'
```